# Thread waiting logic

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an object which has just a Set of string. I can add names to the String at any point of time. I am setting 5 seconds as the max waiting time to finish adding the names to set. After that i am printing all the names in the Set. So I have defined the following class for my Object.

```
public class FamilyGroup {
    Set<String> names;
    private long id;

    public FamilyGroup(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        names = new HashSet<String>();
    }

    public void addName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
    }

    public void displayFamilyMembers() {
        for (String string : names) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

I am submitting this job to a Runnable which is as follows,

```
public class FamilyWaiterThread implements Runnable {
    private FamilyGroup group;
    private final long MAX_WAITING_TIME = 1000 * 15;

    FamilyWaiterThread(FamilyGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(MAX_WAITING_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        group.displayFamilyMembers();
    }
}
```

This code waits for 15 seconds, and then successfully prints all the names in the set. This is how i am testing it.

```
public class FamilyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FamilyGroup familyGroup1 = new FamilyGroup(1L);
        familyGroup1.addName("Shane Lee");
        FamilyWaiterThread familyWaiterThread1 = new FamilyWaiterThread(familyGroup1);
        new Thread(familyWaiterThread1).start();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        familyGroup1.addName("Bret Lee");
    }
}
```

I am adding the name "Bret Lee" 2 seconds after spawning the new thread, that new thread waits for 15 seconds and prints both names. Output is

```
Shane Lee
Bret Lee
```

Suppose if i add the name "Bret Lee" after 16 seconds,

```
Thread.sleep(16000);
familyGroup1.addName("Bret Lee");
```

it is printing only "Shane Lee" since the thread waits only for 15 seconds.
Now i want to add one more functionality. I want the thread to stop waiting if there is no name added for 5 continuous seconds and print the output. If any name is added within 5 seconds the thread should continue to listen to the maximum of 15 seconds. To summarize, my max waiting time for the group object is 15 secs. After 15 secs i am surely printing the output and if there is no name adding for atleast 5 seconds i am printing the output.I could not figure out a way to achieve this.Any ideas are welcome, since i am new to multithreading.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called [Watchdog Timer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer). In the constructor of FamilyGroup you create two watchdog timers: The first with period 15 s, the second with period 5 s. You reset the latter every time a name is added. The first timer that ticks, prints the names. **Watch out** you need the proper synchronization primitives to avoid data races.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to get the desired output. Thanks guys!!

```
public class FamilyWaiterThread implements Runnable {
    private FamilyGroup group;
    private boolean hasSomthingNew = true;
    private final long MAX_WAITING_TIME = 1000 * 10;
    private final long MAX_INACTIVE_TIME = 1000 * 3;

    FamilyWaiterThread(FamilyGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public boolean hasSomethingNew() {
        return hasSomthingNew;
    }

    public void setHasSomethingnew(boolean value) {
        hasSomthingNew = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!timeOut(startTime) && hasSomethingNew()) {
            hasSomthingNew = false;
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (((startTime + MAX_WAITING_TIME) - currentTime) < MAX_INACTIVE_TIME) {
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(MAX_INACTIVE_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        long afterWhileLoop = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Total waiting time " + (afterWhileLoop - startTime));
        group.displayFamilyMembers();
        System.out.println("__________________________________");
    }

    private boolean timeOut(long startTime) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((currentTime - startTime) > MAX_WAITING_TIME) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a very simple solution, you could use a flag in your `FamilyGroup` class that signals if new data has been inserted. Something like `public boolean HasSomethingNew = false`  that is set `true` in `addName()` method and set `false` in `displayFamilyMembers` method.
Then you need a loop in your Thread `run` method like this

```
@Override
public void run() {
    boolean EndThread = false;
    int WaitingRuns = 0;
    while(!EndThread){
        while(!group.HasSomethingNew && WaitingRuns < 3){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WaitingRuns++;
        }
        if(group.HasSomethingNew){
            group.displayFamilyMembers();
            WaitingRuns = 0;
        } else EndThread = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the `FamilyWaiterThread`. I have added a instance of Thread with variable name `second`(second thread) ..

After 15 seconds when set is printed the second `Thread`starts... It runs for 5s if the add method doesn't stop it.. It prints or else it doesn't.. And yes it's tested..

Thank you ... Good question Btw...!!

```
public class FamilyWaiterThread implements Runnable {
private FamilyGroup group;
private final long MAX_WAITING_TIME = 1000 * 15;
Thread second = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            System.out.println("Before adding");
            group.displayFamilyMembers();
        }
    };
FamilyWaiterThread(FamilyGroup group) {
    this.group = group;
}
FamilyWaiterThread(){}

@Override
public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(MAX_WAITING_TIME);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    group.displayFamilyMembers();
    second.start();
}
 }
```

And this is the small change in FamilyGroup

```
public void addName(String name) {
    names.add(name);
    new FamilyWaiterThread().second.stop();
}
```